# Pigeonhole principle in a congruence problem

Tags: number-theory

Let $m$ be a positive integer, let $1\leq n \leq m$ be an integer coprime to $m$. I want to show that there exists an integer $l \in \{1,2,\ldots,\lceil \sqrt{m}\rceil\}$ such that $ln \equiv i \pmod m$ with $1\leq i\leq \sqrt{m}$.

What I have in hand is that since $(m,n)=1$, so for any $l\not\equiv l' \pmod m$, we always have $ln\not \equiv l'n \pmod m$. Then I think I need to find $l_{1},l_{2} \in \{1,2,\ldots,\lceil \sqrt{m}\rceil+1\}$ such that $l_{1}n-l_{2} n\equiv n(l_{1}-l_{2})\equiv i$ with $1\leq i\leq \sqrt{m}$. But I am not sure how to use pigeonhole here to obtain the conclusion.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k=\lceil\sqrt{m}\rceil$ then $k^2>m$. Divide the elements in $\mathbb{Z_m}$ into $k$ bins:

$1 \text{ to } k$

$k+1 \text { to } 2k$

...

$k(k-1)+1 \text { to } m$.

Can you end it now?

Comment: I think I get it. Let $l_{i}$ rang from $1$ to $m$, then $nl$ would rang from $1$ to $m$ too. So we have $m$ pigeons going to $k$ holes, there must be a hole with multiple pigeons. Next look at the hole with the most pigeons, the number is at least $k$, so the minimum distance between two pigeons would be at most $m/k=k$. So we have two pigeons in the same hole and differ less than $k$.

Comment: Now I am wondering if there is an argument to improve $\sqrt{m} $ to something like $\sqrt[3]{m}$.....

Comment: There should be only $k$ pigeons. If any of them is in hole #1 (1 to k) then you are done. If not then all are in holes #2, 3, ..., k, so two must be in the same hole and then you take the difference.

Comment: What is the "pigeon" stands for in your argument?

Comment: $ln$, where $l=1, 2, \ldots, k$

Comment: BTW I don't think you can improve that much. If $n=k+1$, then you must have $nk\ge m$, or $k(k+1)=k^2+k>m$.

Comment: Ok, I agree for $l=1,\ldots,k$, the number of pigeons is $k$. In my argument, I put $l=1,\ldots,m$ and I think that also works.

Comment: Yes, finding an improvement is not easy.